# Regex PCRE2 verify range of ip address

Tags: php, regex, ip-address, pcre, pcre2

Currently I'm working on a regular expression wrote in PCRE2 to check a range of IP address

```
^(10\.).+|(172\.16).+|(192\.168).+
```

**I need the regular expression to check also if in the string I can find any ip between 172.16.X.X - 172.31.X.X**

The current regex it's working but not checking this range specifically ... it's capturing everything that's **172.16.X.X**

I tried `^(10\.).+|(172\.[16-31]).+|(192\.168).+` but It doesn't work in this way.

Also I'm using https://regex101.com/ to debug this expression ... is it a good way to check if it's right?

Comment: Like this? `\b172\.(?:1[789]|2\d|3[01])\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` https://regex101.com/r/04KJxW/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird https://regex101.com/r/2q8nF1/1 this new one isn't capturing the other specification ... can you see? Should I substitute the whole capturing group to this whole expression?

Comment: Frame challenge: have you considered using a library that can validate based on an address range in CIDR notation, instead of building a regular expression?

Comment: @DanielLimaFortes Like this then? https://regex101.com/r/mURVCf/1

Comment: @IMSoP this case works specifically with regex ... I'd be glad if was using any library

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's perfect!! but I miss spelled the range writting it as 172.17.x.x - 172.31.x.x instead of 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x (I edited the question)

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill when you can just use [`ip2long()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long), math, and bitwise/comparison operators. https://www.ccexpert.us/routing-switching/subnetting-math.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:(?:192\.168|172(?:\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])))(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}|10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\b
```

- `\b` A word boudnary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `192\.168` Match 192.168
    - `|` Or
    - `172(?:\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))` Match `172.` and then 16 till 31
  - `)` Close non capture gorup
  - `(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}` Match 2 times `.` and 1-3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` Match 10 and 3 times `.` and 1-3 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsjQ03/1)

If you want to make the `\d{1,3}` digits more specific, then you can also use:

`(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`